# Spark dataframe aggregation scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((a, 1), (a, null), (b, null)(b, 2),(b, 3),(c, 2),(c, 4),(c, 3))).toDF("col1","col2")
```

The output should be like below.

```
col1 col2
a    null
b    null
c    4
```

I knew that groupBy on col1 and get the max of col2. which I can perform using `df.groupBy("col1").agg("col2"->"max")`

But my requirement is if null is there I want to select that record, but if null is not there I want to select max of col2.

How can I do this, can any please help me.

Comment: try using this 
`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`
`df.groupBy("col1").agg(collect_as_list("col2"))` now you have list on col2 try your logic here like if list.contains(null) return null else max from list

Comment: You should really rethink the premise of the question. There is no need to have a bunch of `null` in your RDD.

Comment: Hello all thanks for the response. I have done this in the below way. I first modified dataframe by updating null values to a string '99-99-9999' for that column. Then I did a group by other columns and agg -->max on the column which I updated. So my requirement is fulfilled. Thanks a lot to all who responded.

Comment: @Ramesh : It will be good if you post your answer and accept it. So that if others are searching for similar answer it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, your use of `null` makes things unnecessarily problematic, so if you can't work without `null` in the first place, I think it makes most sense to turn it into something more useful:

```
val df = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((a, 1), (a, null), (b, null), (b, 2),(b, 3),(c, 2),(c, 4),(c, 3)))
        .mapValues { v => Option(v) match {
            case Some(i: Int) => i
            case _ => Int.MaxValue
          }
        }.groupBy(_._1).map {
            case (k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2).max
        }
```

First, I use `Option` to get rid of `null` and to move things down the tree from `Any` to `Int` so I can enjoy more type safety. I replace `null` with `MaxValue` for reasons I'll explain shortly.

Then I `groupBy` as you did, but then I `map` over the groups to pair the keys with the max of the values, which will either be one of your original data items or `MaxValue` where the `null`s once were. If you must, you can turn them back into `null`, but I wouldn't.

There might be a simpler way to do all this, but I like the `null` replacement with `MaxValue`, the pattern matching which helps me narrow the types, and the fact I can just treat everything the same afterwards.